# Dynamic SMTP Configuration in queue laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am working on an application in laravel where the organization can set their own smtp settings being held in database.
I am sending email in my application using laravel **notification classes.**
when i am sending the notifications without QUEUE the configurations are working well for different users
but when the notifications are being processed via the **queue:work --stop when empty**
the smtp settings are not picked up dynamically.
I am using laravel 9

One more things is when i am running the **queue:listen** command the dynamic configurations are working well, but i thing keep running the **queue:listen** on theserver may create some issue. the project is hosted on shared hosting and also on AWS - plesk so if any solutions is possible at hosting end we can try

````
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class TaskActionNotification extends Notification 
{
    use Queueable;

    private $notification;
    public $data;
    public function __construct($notification, $data)
    {
        $this->notification = $notification;
        $this->data = is_array($data) ? (object)$data : $data;
    }
    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {

        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        
        if (!empty($this->data)&&isset($this->data->mailerConfig)) {
            $mailConfigs = $this->data->mailerConfig;
              config(['mail.mailers.smtp' => [
                  'transport' => 'smtp',
                  'host' =>     $mailConfigs->MAIL_HOST,
                  'port' =>     $mailConfigs->MAIL_PORT,
                  'encryption' =>     $mailConfigs->MAIL_ENCRYPTION,
                  'username' =>     $mailConfigs->MAIL_USERNAME,
                  'password' =>     $mailConfigs->MAIL_PASSWORD,
                  'timeout' => null,
                  'auth_mode' => null,
                         ]]);
              config(['mail.from' => [
                  'address' => $mailConfigs->MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS ?? 'project@domain.io',
                  'name' => $mailConfigs->MAIL_FROM_NAME ?? 'compliance',
              ]]);

            }
        $subject =  $this->notification->title;
        $email_body = str_replace('{user}', ucfirst($this->data->user), $this->notification->message);
        $email_body  = str_replace('{reviewer}', $this->data->reviewer, $email_body);
        $email_body  = str_replace('{task}', $this->data->task, $email_body);
        $email_body  = str_replace('{feedback}', $this->data->feedback, $email_body);

        return (new MailMessage)->subject($subject)->markdown(
            'emails.mail',
            ['email_body' => $email_body]
        );
    }

    // public function toMail($notifiable)
    // {
    //     return (new MailMessage)
    //         ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
    //         ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
    //         ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    // }
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}```

this is my sample notification class where i have implemented the current system(without queue)
I have also tried the Notification sending and sent events but thats still not worked for me
````

Comment: Shouldn't you be implementing the `ShouldQueue` interface in your job? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/notifications#queueing-notifications

Also, please paste your queuing code, how are you creating the notification?

Comment: @soulseekah Yes i was using the shouldQueue interface when there was no need for dynamic configurations. since the dynamic configurations were not working with the queue I just removed the implementation to send the notifications directly.

$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty --queue=default')
        //     ->everyMinute()
        //     ->withoutOverlapping();
this is how i have scheduled the queue in console kernel